# ld linker script producing huge binary

Tags: ld, elf, linker-scripts

I'm using `binutils-2.21.53.0.1-6.fc16.x86_64`.

I have a small object file, `hello.o` with just enough "stuff" to have contents in all sections:

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000040
       000000000000005d  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [ 2] .rela.text        RELA             0000000000000000  00000808
       0000000000000060  0000000000000018          15     1     8
  [ 3] .data             PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000000a0
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     4
  [ 4] .bss              NOBITS           0000000000000000  000000a0
       0000000000000053  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     32
  [ 5] .rodata           PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000000a0
       000000000000000f  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 6] .data.rel.local   PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000000b0
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [ 7] .rela.data.rel.lo RELA             0000000000000000  00000868
       0000000000000018  0000000000000018          15     6     8
  [ 8] .data.rel         PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000000b8
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [ 9] .rela.data.rel    RELA             0000000000000000  00000880
       0000000000000018  0000000000000018          15     8     8
  [10] .comment          PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000000c0
       000000000000002d  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
  [11] .note.GNU-stack   PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000000ed
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [12] .eh_frame         PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000000f0
       0000000000000058  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [13] .rela.eh_frame    RELA             0000000000000000  00000898
       0000000000000030  0000000000000018          15    12     8
  [14] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  00000148
       0000000000000085  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [15] .symtab           SYMTAB           0000000000000000  00000610
       00000000000001b0  0000000000000018          16    11     8
  [16] .strtab           STRTAB           0000000000000000  000007c0
       0000000000000045  0000000000000000           0     0     1
```

If I use `-pie` and no linker script, the results are as expected:

```
$ ld -pie -Map hello_pie.map -o hello_pie.elf hello.o 

$ ll hello_pie.elf 
-rwxrwx---. 1 jreinhart jreinhart 3453 Mar 13 23:44 hello_pie.elf
```

However, if I include any sort of linker script, the output size explodes:

```
$ cat 1.ld 
SECTIONS
{

}
$ ld -T 1.ld -pie -Map hello_pie.map -o hello_pie.elf hello.o 
$ ll hello_pie.elf 
-rwxrwx---. 1 jreinhart jreinhart 2100070 Mar 13 23:45 hello_pie.elf
```

As you can see, this file became huge.

Note that this appears to happen because the `.text` section insists on starting at offset 0x200000 in the file:

```
$ readelf -l -S hello_pie.elf 
There are 19 section headers, starting at offset 0x200400:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00200000  <--- Why?
       000000000000005d  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [ 2] .rodata           PROGBITS         000000000000005d  0020005d
       000000000000000f  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 3] .eh_frame         PROGBITS         0000000000000070  00200070
       0000000000000058  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [ 4] .interp           PROGBITS         00000000000000c8  002000c8
       000000000000000f  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 5] .dynsym           DYNSYM           00000000000000d8  002000d8
       0000000000000078  0000000000000018   A       6     2     8
  [ 6] .dynstr           STRTAB           0000000000000150  00200150
       0000000000000014  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 7] .hash             HASH             0000000000000168  00200168
       0000000000000028  0000000000000004   A       5     0     8
  [ 8] .rela.dyn         RELA             0000000000000190  00200190
       0000000000000078  0000000000000018   A       5     0     8
  [ 9] .data.rel.local   PROGBITS         0000000000000208  00200208
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [10] .data.rel         PROGBITS         0000000000000210  00200210
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [11] .dynamic          DYNAMIC          0000000000000218  00200218
       00000000000000f0  0000000000000010  WA       6     0     8
  [12] .got              PROGBITS         0000000000000308  00200308
       0000000000000018  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [13] .got.plt          PROGBITS         0000000000000320  00200320
       0000000000000018  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [14] .bss              NOBITS           0000000000000340  00200338
       0000000000000053  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     32
  [15] .comment          PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00200338
       000000000000002c  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
  [16] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  00200364
       000000000000009a  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [17] .symtab           SYMTAB           0000000000000000  002008c0
       0000000000000258  0000000000000018          18    19     8
  [18] .strtab           STRTAB           0000000000000000  00200b18
       000000000000004e  0000000000000000           0     0     1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), l (large)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)

Elf file type is DYN (Shared object file)
Entry point 0x0
There are 5 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000200040 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000118 0x0000000000000118  R E    8
  INTERP         0x00000000002000c8 0x00000000000000c8 0x00000000000000c8
                 0x000000000000000f 0x000000000000000f  R      1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld64.so.1]
  LOAD       --> 0x0000000000200000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000338 0x0000000000000393  RWE    200000
  DYNAMIC        0x0000000000200218 0x0000000000000218 0x0000000000000218
                 0x00000000000000f0 0x00000000000000f0  RW     8
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     8
```

This has been happening regardless of the contents of my linker script.  Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Do you have symbol tables also generated??

Comment: You can see that there is a `.symtab` section, whose length has nothing to do with this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default `ld` page-aligns input sections. Since your kernel enforces superpages (pages of 2MB = 0x200000 bytes) your `.text` section gets aligned at offset 0x200000. It seems like a bug in `ld` as it should use offset 0x0000000 instead (see EDIT below for a possible explanation)

To prevent this alignment which creates a bigger file, you can use the `--nmagic` flag to ld to prevent it from page-aligning your .text section although it has side effects (it also disables linking against shared libraries). Be careful though to align other sections (`.data`, `.rodata`,...) to 2M pages because they can't live in the same page as .text since all these sections require different access bits.

EDIT: thinking about it, we all expect accesses to virtual address 0x00000000 to generate an exception (segfault). To do so, I see two possibilities: either the kernel maps a page with no access rights (r/w/x) or (more likely) it simply doesn't map anything (no page mapped => segfault) and the linker must know that somehow... that could explain why ld skips the first page which is at address zero. This is TBC.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this same problem today when learning about linker scripts. SIZEOF_HEADERS was the magic bullet to solve it. Here is my simple source file to build the object I'm linking:

```
    .section .text
    .global _start
_start:
    mov $1, %eax
    mov $8, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

With the following linker script, I get a 2+ MB executable:

```
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x400000;
    .text : { *(.text) }
}
```

If I add +SIZEOF_HEADERS, as shown below, I get a 568-byte executable:

```
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x400000 + SIZEOF_HEADERS;
    .text : { *(.text) }
}
```

Per the [LD documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Builtin-Functions.html), this function returns the size of the output file's headers. Manually setting the offset to include the header size also yields a 568-byte executable:

```
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x400078;
    .text : { *(.text) }
}
```

If I move .text even further down, the executable starts to expand. The following yields a 65984-byte executable:

```
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x410000;
    .text : { *(.text) }
}
```

So basically, from what I can tell, it appears that:

- The first output section appears to share a memory page with the output file headers. If the first section overlaps with the headers, LD emits a full page of pad bytes before outputting the first section to avoid a conflict
- To fix this, set the output address for the first output section to X + SIZEOF_HEADERS. This is what the built-in linker script for LD does (you can take a look by running "ld --verbose")

Comment: I may be pretty dense, but when I do this with the line `. = 0x10000 + SIZEOF_HEADERS` I still get a "huge" binary.  I change it to `. = 0x400000 + SIZEOF_HEADERS` and it gets small again.  Do you know why that might be?

Comment: Hmm, I tried `-n` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36649501/binutils-ld-creates-huge-files) and it got small again.  I guess I need to learn more about "page alignment" and its implications...

Answer (score 6):

Try the following command line option with ld (or gcc):

```
-z max-page-size=0x1000
```