# Binutils LD creates huge files

Tags: ld, compiler-optimization, binutils

I'm trying to create as small ELF as possible. I created a test file like this (NASM syntax):

```
SECTION .text
dd 0xdeadbeef
```

With this linker script:

```
SECTIONS {
    .text : {
        *(.text)
    }
}
```

Then I checked sizes of flat binary and ELFs built two ways:

```
nasm -f bin -o test test.asm
```

It's flat binary, so 4 bytes.

```
nasm -f elf -o test.o test.asm
i686-elf-ld -Tlinker.ld test.o -o test
```

I'd expect something like 500 bytes max, but the resulting file is 4396 bytes long! There is an option however, named --strip-all, that could make this file smaller.

```
i686-elf-ld -Tlinker.ld test.o -o test --strip-all
```

4244 bytes. Still huge.

Why is LD generating so big files? Is there a way to make it smaller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linker is page aligning your text section to the nearest page boundary so that [demand paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demand_paging) can be used.

```
$ objdump --headers -f test

test:     file format elf32-i386
architecture: i386, flags 0x00000102:
EXEC_P, D_PAGED
start address 0x00000000

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .text         00000004  00000000  00000000  00001000  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
```

Notice the "Align" column of the text section is set to 4KB. Because of the alignment is set to 4Kb and demand paging is in use (D_PAGED), the .text section is located 4Kb into the file. Your text section is only 4 bytes long.

Link with `-n` to disable demand paging:

```
$ ld -Tlinker.ld test.o -o test --strip-all -n
$ objdump --headers -f test

test:     file format elf32-i386
architecture: i386, flags 0x00000002:
EXEC_P
start address 0x00000000

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .text         00000004  00000000  00000000  00000060  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
$ ls -l test
-rwxrwxr-x 1 mikel mikel 240 Apr 15 12:31 test
```